# addIncomingCall in Android TelecomManager not doing anything

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the native Android incoming call UI. I've got a connectionService and I've succesfully registered a phone Account. But nothing at all happens after I call the method addNewIncomingCall. Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Manifest...

```
<service
    android:name=".MyConnectionService"
    android:label="example"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Activity...

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
            new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MyConnectionService.class),
            "example");

    PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "example").setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER).build();
    tm.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL, mNumber.getText().toString(), null);
    extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_ADDRESS, uri);
    extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, phoneAccountHandle);
    tm.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, extras);

}
```

MyConnectionService where I'm hoping to at least see something in Log generated by onCreateIncomingConnection

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
 public class MyConnectionService extends ConnectionService {

 private static String TAG = "MyConnectionService";


public MyConnectionService() {
}


@Override
public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle      connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
Log.i(TAG,"onCreateIncomingConnection");
return    super.onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request);
}
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it running too.  But the incoming call UI, when the phone is locked, contains no actions to answer or reject the call. Do you have any idea what might be the reason?

Answer (score 5):

I renamed MyConnectionService to simply MyService - started working. Weird!

Comment: I have seen this too. After several reinstalls the service stops working and needs to be renamed. The logs show that Android telecom system tries to instantiate the class, but then nothing. Uninstalling the app does not help. Haven't tested restarting the device though.

Comment: Yep, same behavior here.  It's awful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need the answer, but maybe you should try initializing a CallConnection.

```
@Override
public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle 
connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    CallConnection callConnection = new CallConnection();
    callConnection.setInitializing();
    return callConnection;
}
```

And after that you could create a subclass of CallConnection which extends Connection and call the onAnswer() Method.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class CallConnection extends Connection{

    public CallConnection(){
        setConnectionProperties(PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED);
        setAudioModeIsVoip(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnswer(){
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnswer() called");
        //Accept the Call
    }
}
```

Not sure if you need the properties but you could give it a try!

Comment: He's not even getting to the onCreateIncomingConnection callback.