# Trigger Incoming Call UI Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to trigger the incoming call UI on Android by using code from [addIncomingCall in Android TelecomManager not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027292/addincomingcall-in-android-telecommanager-not-doing-anything) but I can't get the incoming call UI to show up.

`onCreateOutgoingConnection` gets called successfully because I'm able to log a message inside that callback.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test.voip;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.PhoneAccount;
import android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle;
import android.telecom.TelecomManager;
import android.telecom.ConnectionService;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.test.voip.*;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import android.telecom.VideoProfile;
import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);


        TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);


        PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
                new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class),
                "example");

        Log.i(TAG, tm.toString());

        PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "abc").setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER).build();
        tm.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        Log.i(TAG, tm.toString());

        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL, "3924823201", null);
        extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_ADDRESS, uri);
        extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, phoneAccountHandle);
        tm.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, extras);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

//    public void sendIncomingCallIntent(Context context, Uri handle,
//                                       boolean isVideoCall) {
//        PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccount = new PhoneAccountHandle(
//                new ComponentName(context, MyService.class),
//                "testapps_TestConnectionService_SIM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
//
//        // For the purposes of testing, indicate whether the incoming call is a video call by
//        // stashing an indicator in the EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS.
//        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
//        extras.putBoolean("abcd",
//                true);
//        if (handle != null) {
//            extras.putParcelable("abc", handle);
//        }
//
//        TelecomManager tmabc = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
//        tmabc.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccount,
//                extras);
//    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test.voip">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:label="example"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

MyService.java

```
package com.example.test.voip;

import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.telecom.ConnectionService;
import android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle;
import android.telecom.ConnectionRequest;
import android.telecom.Connection;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class MyService extends ConnectionService {

    private static String TAG = "MyService";


    public MyService() {
    }


    @Override
    public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateIncomingConnection60");
        Log.i(TAG,connectionManagerPhoneAccount.toString());
        Log.i(TAG,request.toString());
        return super.onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request);
    }

    public Connection onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {

        return super.onCreateOutgoingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount,request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the above code inside `onCreateOutgoingConnection`?

Comment: `MyService.class` leads me to believe this code is inside a Service? Did you put that in your manifest?

Comment: I added the manifest in my edit